# Queue is empty after disconnect/connect operation

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Client application (Windows Forms) that send/receive data simultaneously and stores data into a queue: everything is going fine and queue treating is going well. 
after disconnecting from the remote host (Close connection button) and reconnecting :  an error  "empty queue" appears when sender code reaches dequeuing instruction, I think the Sender class doesn't possess the same queue as the Receiver class after restarting connection. 
Any Ideas?

Client Class:

```
public sealed partial class Client 
{       
    private static Queue<byte[]> q = new Queue<byte[]>();

    public  void clear_q() { q.Clear(); }

    public Client(string IPADRESStxt, string PORTNUMBERtxt)
    {       _client = new TcpClient(IPADRESStxt, Int32.Parse(PORTNUMBERtxt));        }

    public void SendData(byte[] data)
    {            _sender.SendData(data);       }

    public event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;

    public void Connect()
    {
        _stream = _client.GetStream();
        _sender = new Sender(_stream);
        _receiver = new Receiver(_stream);       
        _receiver.DataReceived += OnDataReceived;
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {   _stream.Close();    }

    private void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var handler = DataReceived;
        if (handler != null) DataReceived(this, e);  // re-raise event
    }

    private TcpClient _client;
    private  NetworkStream _stream;

    private Receiver _receiver;
    private Sender _sender;

    private static ManualResetEvent ShutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);}
```

Sender Class (where data is Dequeued):

```
public sealed partial class Client
{
    private sealed class Sender
    {
        internal void SendData(byte[] data)
        {
            _stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }
        internal Sender(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            _stream = stream;
            _thread = new Thread(Run);
            _thread.Start();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
            while (1 == 1)
            {
                lock (q)
                {
                        if (q.Count > 0)
                        {
                        byte[] block1 = q.Dequeue(); //Error appears here
                        Sframe = new byte[] { 0x68, 0x04, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };
                        SendData(Sframe);                                                
                        // code 
                        }
                }
            }
        private NetworkStream _stream;
        private Thread _thread;
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver class (where data is enqueued):

```
public sealed partial class Client
{
    private sealed class Receiver
    {
        internal event EventHandler<DataReceivedEventArgs> DataReceived;

        internal Receiver(NetworkStream stream)
        {
            _stream = stream;
            _thread = new Thread(Run);
            _thread.Start();
        }

        private void Run()
        {
         try{
             if (_stream.Read(m_Bytes, 0, m_Bytes.Length) > 0)                                                 
                            ReadFully(_stream);
             else   ShutdownEvent.Set();                            
            }
            finally
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                _stream.Close();
            }
        }
        public static byte[] ReadFully(Stream input) 
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int read;
                while ((read = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    byte[] newone = new byte[read];
                    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read); 
                    Array.Copy(buffer, newone, read);
                    show_get_frame_one_by_one(newone);
                }
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static void show_get_frame_one_by_one(byte[] buffer) 
        {
                lock(q){ queing(buffer); update_queue_text(true);  }   
        }

        private NetworkStream _stream;
        private Thread _thread;
    }
}
```

Windows forms:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myform = this;
    }

    Client c1;

    public void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        try
        {
            c1 = new Client(IPADRESStext.Text, PORTNUMBERtext.Text);
            c1.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString()); }
    }

    private void CloseButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        c1.Disconnect(); 
    }     
}
```

Comment: Did you try setting up breakpoints and stepping through your code, or do you expect us to have the mental debugging capacity to do that from the code shown?

Comment: I tried debugging , but it is impossible to do that with runtime data exchange ... there are protocol restrictions and timeouts